# Are there closed form solutions available for this equation below?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Solutions for the poisson equation are well known.
$$\nabla^2U=\nabla\times W                           
$$
If one more linear operator$$ \nabla(\nabla\cdot\ U)$$ is present,
$$
\nabla(\nabla\cdot\ U)-\nabla^2U=\nabla\times W
$$
W is a known function of space

How do we solve and which are the sources of information that deal with equations ?

Comment: Please explain your notations: what are $\Delta \times W$ and $\Delta \cdot U$?

Comment: Hi  Fan !! Δ×W is curl of a known function W over space Δ⋅U  is the divergence operator on vector U to be found

Comment: So while you wrote $\Delta$ you actually mean $\nabla$?

Comment: And also, if $\times$ is curl, then $W$ is a function to $\mathbb{R}^3$? I think some mild editing and details into the text would help us all...

Comment: @AmirSagiv My interpretation is that both $U$ and $W$ are vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @ Amir. Please notice mild edits.

Comment: @Fan .Yes Your interpretation is right

Comment: @ Amir @ Fan  I realized we could write the original equation in a simple form by using the vector identity  $$
\nabla(\nabla\cdot\ U)-\nabla^2U=\nabla\times \nabla\times U
$$ The it is just  $$\nabla\times U =W $$ then I have used Green's function method http://mathoverflow.net/questions/251308/how-to-identify-a-correct-green-s-function-for-this-case and got struck in finding the exact green's function.

Answer (score 3):

Now I see. So both your $U$ and $W$ are vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and your equation is more commonly written as

$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot U)-\nabla^2U=\nabla\times W.$$

By the identity of the [vector Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian), your equation can be written as

$$ \nabla\times(\nabla\times U)=\nabla\times W.$$

You can first solve for $\nabla\times U$ by removing $\nabla\times$ from both sides, but remember $\nabla\times U$ is divergence free, so what results is

$$ \nabla\times U=PW,$$

where $PW$ is the divergence free part of $W$ (see [Leray projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray_projection)). Now $U$ can be solved using the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law), but note $U$ is not unique; it can differ by the gradient of a function $\nabla\phi$.

Comment: I guess, to use Biot Savart law one needs to have  $$ \nabla\cdot\ U=0$$ so that it becomes a vector poisson equation  which is not the case here.That is why that term is retained in the beginning itself.Otherwise what u said is true.

Comment: Hey Fan! I realized we could write the original equation in a simple form